# Jquery datepicker do not work in modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

```js
var date = new Date();
var datepickerStartMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
var datepickerStartDate = date.getDate() + "/" + datepickerStartMonth + "/" + date.getFullYear();

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  startDate: datepickerStartDate,
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="">
```

Comment: Share HTML part as well

Comment: Depending on the modal library you're using the content may be cloned. As such you would need to define the `datepicker()` on the `input` element when the modal is displayed, not when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to set default value to your input.
The format need a 0 until the number 10.

```js
var date = new Date();
var datepickerStartDay = date.getDate();
if (datepickerStartDay < 10) datepickerStartDay = "0" + datepickerStartDay; 
var datepickerStartMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
if (datepickerStartMonth < 10) datepickerStartMonth = "0" + datepickerStartMonth; 
var datepickerStartDate = datepickerStartDay + "/" + datepickerStartMonth + "/" + date.getFullYear();

console.log(datepickerStartDate);

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  startDate: datepickerStartDate,
  autoclose: true
}).val(datepickerStartDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="">
```